# JQuery html elements as function argurments

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code seems not to be working. I'm really confused...
Asking for help:

```
function FadeInOut(element) {
  for(;;) {
    element.fadeToggle();
  }
}

$(function() {

  FadeInOut($(".heads"));
}
```

Any thoughts why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: and yeah, I'm really new to jaavascript and jquery, so..

Comment: Of course, a sec...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ubv897L/1/

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are actually trying to achieve? Also, why are you using for( ; ; ) - this will be an infinite loop unless you break out of it? which you're not doing...

Comment: Please post your question more clearly on where you are struck or what your error is...

Answer (score 0):

due to spelling mistake element instead of elements in function:

```
function FadeInOut(element) {
  if(element.length > 0) { // use element here instead of elements
    $(".heads").ht(element.join(", ")); // use element here instead of elements
    for(;;) {
      element.fadeToggle();
    }
  }
}


$(document).ready(function () { // call function inside document.ready
    FadeInOut($('.heads'));
});
```

Comment: Actually, it didn't make any difference, it still does not work.